# Adjusting the size of tables when using esttab

Tags: latex, stata

I am exporting regression results in `tex` files using the *community-contributed* command `esttab`:

```
esttab using reg.tex, nonumbers mtitles("1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9")
```

The table contains nine columns.

I would like to make the font size and the width of columns smaller so that the whole table can fit in the page when I compile the file in `LaTeX`.

Is there a way to do this directly in Stata when I use `esttab`?

Comment: You can add the optional `(fmt)` formatting command to the estimates you request. For example, the option `b(1)` displays your point estimates with only one decimal, instead of the default three. Although this will make your table less wide, it depends on your data whether it is still informative. The `compress` option reduces horizontal spacing, but will not affect your Latex tables. Lastly, you can put the whole table in a landscape page in Latex, which gives you much more horizontal space.

Comment: I used to have this problem all the time. An out-of-the-box solution I started using was exporting to a .csv file, and then using Excel or OpenOfficeCalc to do the edits.  Use "Excel2LaTeX" or "Calc2LaTeX" to convert to tex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following example using Stata's `auto` toy dataset:

```
sysuse auto, clear
eststo clear

eststo: quietly regress price weight
eststo: quietly regress price weight mpg

esttab

--------------------------------------------
                      (1)             (2)   
                    price           price   
--------------------------------------------
weight              2.044***        1.747** 
                   (5.42)          (2.72)   

mpg                                -49.51   
                                  (-0.57)   

_cons              -6.707          1946.1   
                  (-0.01)          (0.54)   
--------------------------------------------
N                      74              74   
--------------------------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

In general, the width of the columns can be controlled using
`varwidth()` and/or `modelwidth()`:

```
esttab, mlabels(none) varwidth(25)

---------------------------------------------------------
                                   (1)             (2)   
---------------------------------------------------------
weight                           2.044***        1.747** 
                                (5.42)          (2.72)   

mpg                                             -49.51   
                                               (-0.57)   

_cons                           -6.707          1946.1   
                               (-0.01)          (0.54)   
---------------------------------------------------------
N                                   74              74   
---------------------------------------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001

esttab, mlabels(none) modelwidth(25)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                   (1)                          (2)   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
weight                           2.044***                     1.747** 
                                (5.42)                       (2.72)   
mpg                                                          -49.51   
                                                            (-0.57)   
_cons                           -6.707                       1946.1   
                               (-0.01)                       (0.54)   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
N                                   74                           74   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

The two aforementioned options can also work in combination:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                (1)                          (2)   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
weight                                        2.044***                     1.747** 
                                             (5.42)                       (2.72)   

mpg                                                                       -49.51   
                                                                         (-0.57)   

_cons                                        -6.707                       1946.1   
                                            (-0.01)                       (0.54)   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
N                                                74                           74   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

For `LaTeX` output you will need to include the necessary markup in the `prehead()` or `postfoot()` options as appropriate.

In this example, you can change the font size of the table as follows:

```
esttab, mlabels(none) tex ///
        prehead(`"\begin{table}"' `"\tiny"' ///
                `"\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}"' ///
                `"\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{c}}"') ///
        postfoot(`"\end{tabular}"' `"\end{table}"')
```

Similarly, you can control the column spacing by changing below the value `{5pt}`:

```
esttab, mlabels(none) tex ///
        prehead(`"\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}"' `"\begin{tabular}"')
```